# SQL conditionally return results from one of two DB columns into single result column

Tags: sql-server

Hello I have the below SQL query that I would like to conditionally return results from one of two DB columns (DEA and DEA_ALT) into one result column depending which of those two columns is valued (not null). The DB is setup where there are two fields that can store a field called DEA# however both fields have the same purpose, and therefore I would like to return the results from either column depending on which one is valued (can be either).

```
SELECT Distinct t1.UserName,
            t1.[LoginID],
            t7.FirstName, 
            t7.LastName, 
            t7.Title ,
            t7.EndDateOfValidity,      
            NPI = ISNULL(HStaffIdentifiers.Value,''),
            Type= HStaffIdentifiers.Type, 
            DEA=ISNULL(t5.PrescriberCode,''),
            --
            --
            DEA_ALT = ISNULL((select CASE ISNULL(PC.PrescriberCode,'')
                          when '' then ISNULL(HS.Value,'')
                          end
                          from HStaff PC
                          left outer join HStaffIdentifiers HS
                          ON PC.ObjectID = HS.Staff_oid
                          where HS.Type = 'DEA'
                          and HS.Staff_oid = HStaffIdentifiers.Staff_oid
                          ),ISNULL(t5.PrescriberCode,'')),
            --
            --
            Speciality = ISNULL(HDataDictionaryItem3.Description,''),
            Preference_Group = HDataDictionaryItem1.Name
        FROM HSUser t1  with (nolock)
             Left Outer JOIN HStaff t5  with (nolock) 
             ON t1.UserName=t5.MSINumber
             LEFT OUTER JOIN HStaffIdentifiers HStaffIdentifiers WITH (NOLOCK)
             ON t5.ObjectID = HStaffIdentifiers.Staff_oid
             AND HStaffIdentifiers.Type = 'NPI'
             JOIN HPerson t6  with (nolock) 
             ON t5.ObjectID=t6.ObjectID
             JOIN HName t7  with (nolock) 
             ON t6.ObjectID=t7.Person_oid   
             and (t7.EndDateOfValidity < '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                or  t7.EndDateOfValidity is null)

             JOIN HDataDictionaryItem HDataDictionaryItem1 WITH (NOLOCK)
             ON t1.PreferenceGroup_oid = HDataDictionaryItem1.ObjectID
                 AND HDataDictionaryItem1.ItemType_oid = 98

left outer join HDataDictionaryItem HDataDictionaryItem3 WITH (NOLOCK)
             ON t5.PrimarySpeciality_oid = HDataDictionaryItem3.ObjectID
             AND HDataDictionaryItem3.ItemType_oid = 43

             WHERE 

              t1.EndTime >= GETDATE()
             AND t1.BeginTime<=GETDATE()  
             AND t5.Active=1
             AND t6.IsDeleted=0
             AND t5.StaffType = 0 
order by  t7.LastName,  t7.FirstName
```

Snippet from the results at the following link:
http://s7.postimg.org/i5xlsjhnv/12_31_2014_10_00_13_AM.jpg

As you can see from the query results (highlighted in red) there are cases when the DEA may only be populated in one of those two columns, however I want the results to be returned to a single column from the DEA column if it is valued, If not, then I want to check to see if DEA_ALT is valued and if so return the result to this single column. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what happens when both the columns are valued

Answer (score 1):

As @NoDisplayName has said you should just use `coalesce`. From what I can tell though I think it can be a bit simpler. Specifically if you are looking to merge the DEA and DEA_ALT you can take this section

```
        DEA=ISNULL(t5.PrescriberCode,''),
        --
        --
        DEA_ALT = ISNULL((select CASE ISNULL(PC.PrescriberCode,'')
                      when '' then ISNULL(HS.Value,'')
                      end
                      from HStaff PC
                      left outer join HStaffIdentifiers HS
                      ON PC.ObjectID = HS.Staff_oid
                      where HS.Type = 'DEA'
                      and HS.Staff_oid = HStaffIdentifiers.Staff_oid
                      ),ISNULL(t5.PrescriberCode,'')),
```

and write it like this

```
Coalesce(t5.PrescriberCode, HStaffIden.Value) As DEA,
```

you will need to add a new table for the DEA values like this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN HStaffIdentifiers HStaffIden WITH (NOLOCK)
         ON HStaffIdentifiers.Staff_oid = HStaffIden.Staff_oid
```

you can then take this Join Condition

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN HStaffIdentifiers HStaffIdentifiers WITH (NOLOCK)
         ON t5.ObjectID = HStaffIdentifiers.Staff_oid
         AND HStaffIdentifiers.Type = 'NPI'
```

And remove the AND condition like this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN HStaffIdentifiers HStaffIdentifiers WITH (NOLOCK)
         ON t5.ObjectID = HStaffIdentifiers.Staff_oid
```

Then add this condition to the where statement to finish the changes

```
AND HStaffIdentifiers.Type = 'NPI'
And HStaffIden = 'DEA'
```

**Edit:** Fixed the result set so that it correctly matches your original query

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need `Isnull` or `coalesce`

```
SELECT ...,Isnull(t5.PrescriberCode, (SELECT CASE Isnull(PC.PrescriberCode, '')
                                           WHEN '' THEN Isnull(HS.Value, '')
                                         END
                                  FROM   HStaff PC
                                         LEFT OUTER JOIN HStaffIdentifiers HS
                                                      ON PC.ObjectID = HS.Staff_oid
                                  WHERE  HS.Type = 'DEA'
                                         AND HS.Staff_oid = HStaffIdentifiers.Staff_oid), Isnull(t5.PrescriberCode, ''))
        ,...
```

Comment: The ISnull worked fine in this case as a subquery, thank you all for the feedback!